# Mail client account colors

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-tab

In the mail client of my Galaxy Tab I have three accounts. In the view "all mailboxes" there is a little line on the left for marking which mail comes from which account.

These colors seem to be defined randomly when creating the account. I can't find the setting where I can change these colors. The last thing I want to do is to delete and create a new account.

The problem is two of the colors are nearly the same.

My Galaxy Tab is rooted but I found nothing in the table "emailProvider.db".

How can I fix this?

Comment: You actually used to be able to change the color at some point, if I'm remembering correctly. It used to be that you could select an account then hit `Menu->Settings` and the option was there. I think it disappeared when I installed Gingerbread, though...

Comment: unfortunately not. Do you mean in the accountManager? I found nothing. I can set there my name, signature, ringtone, but no color.

Comment: Maybe I was misremembering then. I could have sworn it was there in Froyo, but I definitely don't have the ability to change the colors in Gingerbread. Seems like a bit of an oversight, and it's bugged me in the past, too :-/

Comment: what a pity. My Firmware version is 2.2

Comment: What if you add the same account again (under a different name) so that it gets a different and more distinct color?  You can then remove the original account.

Comment: Hi Chank, as i wrote, of course, i can remove and add an account. But my favority way would be to define a color by settings. Thats the reason for asking all the experts here. BR Frank

Answer (score 1):

Is a third-party mail client a possibility? If yes, I'd recommend [K-9 Mail](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9), works great for me. And yes, it supports changing account colors.

Answer (score 0):

eMail color is based on a fixed list of colors.
Every time you create an eMail account you get the next color, regardless it has already been used.
Every smartphone model has its own color list.
On my **Samsung S5** the list is as follows (RGB code and most similar color):

```
D74979 Red
3493F6 Blue
E07E00 Orange
18A1B2 Navy
8747DB Purple
D0B400 Gold
D72925 Red
32C47A Green
B16865 Red
B1B407 Green
2A67C4 Blue
B04993 Purple
0F9217 Green
DA5C1F Orange
836583 Purple
5C6E84 Navy
6B7CA3 Grey
4D8281 Green
7D7B46 Green
AB8655 Brown
```

If you want a particular color you only need to add and remove the eMail account until you get the color you prefer.

Comment: Any information on where one can find this list on the device, or its proper name?