# Change combined inbox account colors

Tags: email, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.
I have 3 email accounts set up in the email client and I would like to change the colors assigned to each of the accounts.
Is it possible? I haven't been able to find any setting to do it. In [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8475/23285) they say it's not possible in Android 2.2, but how about 4.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried on my Galaxy S3 and I couldn't find a way to do this.

Searching on the web returns nothing more (aside of trying to delete/recreate an account until it's given the color you want, which I didn't try).

You can use another mail client than the one pre-installed on the GS3.

I've tried the following ones:

- MailDroid: great one, possible to choose the color for each account from a palette, free version is ad-based
- AquaMail: good one too, you can choose the color for each account from 8 predefined colors, free version has no ads
- K-9 Mail: possible to choose the color for each account from a palette, no ads, but looks a bit old

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced email from the market will allow to choose account and notification colors for each account. However it lacks the subject in the notification, which is why I stick with stock.

Comment: Your suggestion to use another email client is a good one. It would be more useful if you also include a link to the app you're suggesting.